# display all items in an array of objects with each or jQuery .map()

Tags: arrays, json, each

I have an array of objects like this in a JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Name":"John Doe",
    "Age":46,
    "Hometown":"Anytown, USA",
  },
  {
    "Name":"Jane Q. Public",
    "Age":23,
    "Hometown":"Mayberry, NC",
  },
  {
    "Name":"Andrew Andrews",
    "Age":62,
    "Hometown":"New York, NY"
  },
]
```

I need to convert it to HTML with this format:

```
<div class="person">
<h2>Name</h2>
<p class="name">John Doe</p>
<h2>Age</h2>
<p class="age">46</p>
<h2>Hometown</h2>
<p class="hometown">Anytown, USA</p>
</div> 
...
```

Would it be best to use jQuery's `.map()` for this? Or `each` ? How should I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the [loadJSON plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/), which is very handy in creating an HTML template from actual HTML. I'd still be interested in a .map() or `each` way to do it.